# Sentinel loop won't run

Tags: c++

My program will compile but I'm running into a couple problems. My first `cout` statement requiring `e/E` to end works, but in my second while loop where I state `(+ || - || * || /)` won't run. `+/-/*//` returns "Operation type invalid". Can you guys help me see my error?

First sentinel loop, just learning loops:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOne;
    int numTwo;
    int result;
    string operation;

    cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
    cin >> operation;
    while (operation == "e" || "E")
    {
        cout << "Operation type invalid." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
        cin >> operation;
    }

    while (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/")
    {
        cout << "Please enter integer one: " << endl;
        cin >> numOne;
        cout << "Please enter integer two: " << endl;
        cin >> numTwo;

    if (operation == "+")
    {
        result = numOne + numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << "." << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
    }
    else if (operation == "-")
    {
        result = numOne - numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << "." << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
    }
    else if (operation == "*")
    {
        result = numOne * numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
    }
    else if (operation == "/")
    {
        if (numTwo == 0)
        {
                cout << "You cannot divide by zero!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
        result = numOne / numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
        }
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (operation == "e" || "E")
```

Here you are comparing one of two conditions:

1. Does `operation` == `"e"`?
2. If not, is `"E"` a valid pointer?

That second condition is your problem: `"E"` is of course a valid pointer, so that condition will always be `true`. Always. Notice that in the second condition, you are not comparing `operation` to `"E"`.

You are forever stuck here:

```
while (operation == "e" || "E")
{
    cout << "Operation type invalid." << endl;
    cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
    cin >> operation;
}
```

You simply need to have:

```
while (operation == "e" || operation == "E")
```

This is probably just a typo or an oversight more than anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes that was definitely an oversight more than anything. I made sure to fix that in my second while loop and I guess I just overlooked it.